# Is there a way to see HDD average response rate like on windows?

Tags: kubuntu, 20.10

this is my first time writing in here. so, sorry if i did something wrong.
so here's my question, Is there a way to see HDD response rate(in ms) and Disk active rate like on windows 10?
Im using Kubuntu 20.10.

Comment: um, no, iotop doesn't show hdd response rate.

Comment: Did you notice that there are multiple answers?

Comment: Those don't show the HDD response rate though. unless Im seeing things lol